# Airtable not showing in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, gatsby, airtable

today I tried to use Airtable in GraphQL, however, it does not show in graphql.
I added the package with yarn, then I updated the gatsby-config file with the code below:

```js
   
  require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})

  
  module.exports = {
   {
   plugins: [
      resolve: `gatsby-source-airtable`,
      options: {
        apiKey: process.env.GATSBY_AIRTABLE_API,
        concurrency: 5,
        tables: [
          {
            baseId: process.env.GATSBY_AIRTABLE_BASE_ID,
            tableName: `Projects`,
            mapping: {image:`fileNode`}
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
 }
```

On top of that I cleaned gatsby cache and started gatsby develop with sudo command. Still allAirtable is not showing in the graphiQL

Comment: The environment files are properly created?

Comment: Yes, both files contain API and Base values and are placed in the root folder.
While running "gatsby develop" the terminal throws an error: 
"warn Error fetching tables: Could not find what you are looking for(NOT_FOUND)[Http code 404]

 ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"gatsby-source-airtable" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:



warn The gatsby-source-airtable plugin has generated no Gatsby nodes. Do you need it?"

Comment: It seems a configuration issue... Does the environment variables properly set? Double-check the naming (`GATSBY_AIRTABLE_API`, etc) or the table name

Comment: The naming is correct 100%. Not sure about the table? The table has 4 lines and 3 columns. The base and API copied straight from Airtable so there is no error whatsoever.
I tried to make a new, clean copy of gatsby project and only tried to implement the Airtable with exactly the same error. 

Comment: Why are you running gatsby with `sudo`? Anyway your config looks correct so maybe try regenerating the API key, check you're using a table name not the name of a view or something like that, check you're using the latest version of the source plugin etc.